# Huge diference between MVC View News counter and Google Analytics

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-analytics

I have a counter that counts the number of times a View is presented:

```
public class News
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePostedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }  
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Meta { get; set; }
    public string UrlSlug { get; set; }
    public bool Popular { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public int Views { get; set; }         // <---- COUNTER
}
```

Everytime the page is loaded, I have +1 to Views:

```
public virtual ActionResult Detail(string urlSlug)
{
    News news = db.News
                    .Include("Category")
                    .Where(n => n.UrlSlug.Equals(urlSlug))
                    .FirstOrDefault();

    NewsDetailVM vm = Mapper.Map<News, NewsDetailVM>(news);

    vm.RelatedNews = db.News
                        .Where(r => r.Category.Id == news.Category.Id)
                        .Where(r => r.Hidden == false)
                        .Where(r => r.Id != news.Id)
                        .OrderByDescending(r => r.DateCreated)
                        .Take(3)
                        .Select(r => new NewsRelatedVM()
                        {
                            Title = r.Title,
                            Date = r.DateCreated,
                            UrlSlug = r.UrlSlug,
                            CategoryName = r.Category.Name,
                            CategoryURLSlug = r.Category.UrlSlug,
                            PictureURL = r.Pictures.Where(p => p.Type == 2).FirstOrDefault().Filename
                        })
                        .ToList();

    vm.CategoriesList = db.Categories
                        .Where(c => c.Channel == 1)
                        .Project().To<NewsListCategoryItemVM>()
                        .ToList();

    news.Views = news.Views + 1;    // <-- COUNTER UPDATE

    db.SaveChanges();

    return View(vm);
}
```

The issue is that for example on saturday I have 6464 for the news plublished on that day, and Google analytics presents 2359 pageviews for the News Controller.

From where is coming this diference? Am I doing something wrong with the counter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't rely on Entity Framework to update a counter like this, as it will pull the latest value into memory, alter it in memory and then save it to the database.

If multiple people hit your action method at the same time, then they could each increment the same value by 1 and save it back to the database.  You need to perform a lock on the value in your database whilst it is being updated.

Either that or allow the database to do what it does best, which is manage updates 
like this, you can achieve this by using a stored procedure instead, such as the one I've just drummed up below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_increment_count (@newsId int)

  UPDATE dbo.News SET Views = Views + 1 WHERE id = @newsId 
  GO
```

And then call the procedure from your code using entity framework:

```
SqlParameter newsId = new SqlParameter("@newsId", news.Id);
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("usp_increment_count @newsId", newsId);
```

I hope that this helps.

Comment: Hi Luke, thanks! But if the operation is just to present the News based on a Select, is it not a very fast operation that can make the update in just one visit and avoid the issue that you present?

Comment: I know what you're saying, but EF carries a lot of weight.  You're doing a select of some data, then some more data, mapping both result sets to objects in between selecting the data and incrementing the counter.  The only guaranteed way to increment the counter is to allow the database engine to handle it for you :).

Comment: Were you able to get to the bottom of this?

Comment: I got a bit confused with @Chris's answer, if I change the way I make the count, I may need to build some filters that I am not familiar with :(

Comment: Hi! Thanks, I am going with your solution ;)

Answer (score 7):

It's next to impossible to say what the exact cause of the disparity is, but there's a few likely culprits. First, GA is likely ignoring bots, particularly GoogleBot. However, your methodology here doesn't take bots indexing your site into account. For example, every time GoogleBot hits this view, it's incrementing in the database, but not in GA. You'll need to either exclude this view from access via spiders or find some way to filter out requests from bots.

Second, GA may be filtering out duplicate hits. For example, let's say a user lands on the view and then hits the refresh button 50 times. Your database count just got incremented 50 times, but GA likely still counts this only as a single pageview. In general, you should throttle your counter, by recording the REMOTE_IP and only incrementing if that IP hasn't accessed the page in some period of time like 15 minutes. Then, you at least wouldn't be recording every refresh.

Finally, the counts will always be off in this scenario, since not every client supports or has JavaScript enabled (meaning GA can't track those clients), and the privacy settings of the client may also prevent GA from tracking. Whereas, this database count will count every single request, whether you want it to or not.

Comment: Hi Crhis, thanks! It seems very complex to avoid or minimize the difference... :(

Comment: Any suggestion or example?

Comment: Hi! thanks for your help. I am going with the SP solution for now ;)

Answer (score 2):

The counts are not measuring exactly the same thing and neither is 100% accurate.

Your Entity Framework code will not work if there are concurrent accesses.  See [Concurrency with EF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). The article shows you how you could modify your table and program to make the count accurate.  A solution with a stored procedure looks like it will work with your example, but is not a general solution as it will also fail unless all changes are done in the stored procedure.  This is easier in EF6.

Google Analytics has its own set of issues.  There are lots of articles giving details, here is a [sample article](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2016/01/13/20-reasons-your-google-analytics-pageviews-are-wrong/).  Do not discount coding issues in the client side code.

A solution you might consider is the creation of a new table to track access.  This solves the EF concurrency issues with little effort.  At a minimum, the new table rows would contain a primary key and news Id columns.  Simply add a new row on each read. Then access the counts with a separate query, with the appropriate index this should be quick enough.  The advantage of this approach is you can add extra information like time of access, the source of access and whatever else you need to reconcile or justify your counts.

Another thing you might try to help resolve your issue is the analysis of the web server logs.  The are lots of options, Wikipedia is a good place to start, search 'web server log analysis'.  Again, these are measuring slightly different things and will give different counts.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your help. I am going with the SP solution for now ;)